# The complex meanings of tag:complexity

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [complexity](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complexity) has a number of meanings.  Some of which are already covered by other tags.

In particular, the 100 or so questions seem to fall into one of three groups:

- Really about [big-o](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-o)
- Really about [cyclomatic-complexity](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyclomatic-complexity)
- Hand wavy complexity.

#### The proposal:

- Retag all the [complexity](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complexity) questions about big o, as [big-o](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-o)
- Retag all the [complexity](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complexity) questions about cyclomatic complexity, as [cyclomatic-complexity](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyclomatic-complexity).
- Leave the hand wavy complexity questions there

  - Change the tag wiki to reflect that this is about hand-wavy questions.
  - Get SE to update the tag guidance on [complexity](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complexity) to mention the other two tags.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be tagged with the "complexity" tag?

Comment: Since they are so closely related, does it make sense to have separate tags for [tag:big-o] and friends? Would a single tag [tag:bachmann-landau-notation] make sense?

Comment: @JörgWMittag possibly, though we could also make use of tag synonyms.  That said, I think that most people are going to search for Big O.  Another question would be if [tag:algorithm-analysis] should be cleaned up and made a synonym of big-o (or vice versa).

Comment: [Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity) (which you call a bit handwavy) is more than [computational complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory), which is more than [algorithm analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms), which is more than only [big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). They should not be made synonyms - although a cleanup (retagging) might be appropriate.

Comment: @Bergi there are indeed computational complexity, and algorithm analysis complexity... but there's also questions like [What is the rule for simplicity over complexity?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/258252/) and [How to know whether to create a general system or to hack a solution](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/258252/) and [Simplicity-efficiency tradeoff](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/241444/) and [Fields vs method arguments](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/211252/) which are tagged complexity, but a bit hand wavy in their use of the word.

Answer (score 1):

The proposal to disambiguate the complexity tag is a good one.

Having discrete tags for "big-o" and "cyclomatic complexity" would I'm sure be useful for people who have questions about these specific topics.

As for "hand wavy complexity" (an amusing term(!) for story point complexity estimation which you got from [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238478/planning-poker-with-visually-impaired-colleague?noredirect=1#comment531359_238478)), I'd suggest using the tag "story points", as story points are used to represent the complexity of a story in Agile estimation (see this article [here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/07/story-points-complexity-effort) for more information).

Comment: The other option was [wibbly wobbly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vY_Ry8J_jdw) complexity.

Comment: @MichaelT Lol! :) FYI, I don't have enough reputation to create a "story-points" tag in the linked question. I reckon it would be a good tag to have available for the aforementioned type of question.

Comment: The key to a tag being created and sticking around with value is to find a few questions that would fit.  This does two things - it helps verify that there isn't already another tag out there, and it also makes sure the tag sticks. Single use tags are deleted after six months (if this question is tagged with story-points, and nothing else is for six months, the tag is deleted.  If two questions exist with story-points tag, it doesn't get deleted). So, find a couple questions that should get the story-points tag, post a meta question asking for the tag to be added to them, and it will be done.

Comment: @MichaelT I know that. There are no suitable tags currently...